# Access report details - change visibility of an object for each row

Tags: ms-access, macros, icons, visibility

This is my first question on this forum, I'm a very novice databaser, don't have coding skills unfortunately, but I can macro ok and I'm pretty handy with a cut-and-paste VBA code :-)

I have a report within a form, and essentially I want icons to represent if one of any 4 data elements are present for each row of the report - as represented by 'X's in my picture.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCg7W.jpg)  For example I allow the user to set a reminder date to check on new results - I want an icon to be visible if they've set a reminder for that row.

So far I've tried a few things without success, including having a subreport within the report detail with an 'if data present then browse to' macro (in either the report/"onLoad" or detail/"onPrint" events, or an 'if data present change visible property' macro for a picture or other report detail element.  In short, I can't find a way to change anything in the detail section of the report per row other than the pure data contained within the referenced tables.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this which I just haven't thought of yet, but any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the OnFormat event of the detail section. Assuming you have a field in the recordsource called optFlag and a label in the detail section called lblHello:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If ([optFlag]) Then 
        lblHello.Visible = True
    Else
        lblHello.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The trick is that this event ***only fires*** when you open the report in Print Preview. It will not fire when you open the report in Report View.